# What's the common and scientific name of this plant?

Tags: identification, flowers

[image]

Some people have told me it's frangipani but in my opinion, the petals are too fragile for it to be frangipani?

I need to know for my school project.

Answer (score 3):

It's Catharanthus roseus, commonly known as madagascan periwinkle, though in America, most commonly known as Vinca - it's not related to true Vinca, but was once named Vinca roseus. It comes in a range of flower colours -the veinal marking down the centre of the leaf is more noticeable in some varieties than others. Image and info here https://www.gardensonline.com.au/GardenShed/PlantFinder/Show_2762.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that this is an oleander, Nerium oleander.

(they have various flower colors from white to read)

[image]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerium

Comment: I'm not convinced, because of form of leaves and venetion.

Comment: @Giacomo Oleanders are known to have, to some extent, a variety of leaves in terms of shapes. But all have a whitish line in the middle, like the one from the question, so this matches. Of course, I would be glad if someone come up with a better ID.